# How do I solve Missing mandatory value for "image" option in service "wacore" in Initial Setup of Whatsapp business Api?

Tags: facebook, docker, whatsapp

I am trying to set up for Whatsapp business API.
Referring to the [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance) for setup.

I am working on windows 10 OS. -- Just for Info.

In the section initial setup, on command `docker-compose up -d` I get the error.

> Missing mandatory value for "image" option in service "wacore": Run
>   docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.21.4
>   docker-compose  )

Thank You.

Comment: You have to setup an environment variable WA_API_VERSION with the value of the WhatsApp Business API version that you want to use. 
See https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842 to see how to setup environment variable.
See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/changelog to see the available WhatsApp versions.

Answer (score 9):

You have to define the environment variable for WA_API_VERSION, if you are using powershell run **$env:WA_API_VERSION = "2.23.4"** and then run **docker-compose up -d**

Answer (score 5):

In case setting the environment variable do not work, you can try to change the **WA_API_VERSION** manually inside docker-compose.yml.

Change these lines

```
wacore:
   image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose...<options>)}

...

waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose...<options>)}
```

into

```
wacore:
   image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.23.4

...

waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.23.4
```

for the version number, you can refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/changelog)

Comment: You is my life saver! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The docs says you have to change the version manually

> docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  ...
  wacore:
      image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v${WA_API_VERSION:-2.21.6}
  ...
  waweb:
      image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:-2.21.6}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command like this =>
WA_API_VERSION=2.37.1 docker-compose up -d